# Display the value selected when ionic toggle is true

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app I have set ionic toggle to a list of phone numbers from the json array. The problem Im facing here is when toggle of a specific number is selected, all the toggles are getting selected and set to true. So Im not able to display the selected phone numbers in the alert.All I need is to select multiple phones and list the selected phone numbers in the alert.

Controller:

```
 $scope.notify = function () {
       alert($scope.adminAccess.checked);
    }

    $scope.adminAccess={checked:true};
});
```

Html:

```
   <ion-list>
            <ion-toggle ng-model="adminAccess.checked" ng-repeat="numbers in phoneList" toggle-class="toggle-positive">
                {{numbers.userId}}
            </ion-toggle>
```

Comment: You are applying adminAccess.checked on ng-repeat which means same model is going to pass to every toggle and hence every toggle will get selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ng-model as `number.admin_access`

```js
var carService = angular.module('carService', ['ionic'])
carService.controller('carBrand', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.phoneList = [{
    "userId": 1,
    "admin_access": false,
    "number": "123"
  }, {
    "userId": 2,
    "admin_access": true,
    "number": "456"
  }, {
    "userId": 3,
    "admin_access": false,
    "number": "789"
  }];
  
  $scope.notify = function(number){
    alert(number.admin_access);
  }

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='carService'>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.9/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="carBrand">
  <ion-view view-title="Car Type">
    <ion-content ng-contorller="carBrand">
      <ion-toggle ng-model="number.admin_access" ng-change="notify(number)" ng-repeat="numbers in phoneList" toggle-class="toggle-positive">
        {{numbers.userId}}
      </ion-toggle>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying adminAccess.checked on ng-repeat which means same model is going to pass to every toggle and hence every toggle will get selected.

You need to pass an array of adminAccess object equal to your phoneList(which i assume will be better if included in phoneList)

In Controller:

```
//Add adminAccess attribute in $scope.phoneList like this
$scope.phoneList = [{'userId':'133sf', adminAccess:{checked:true}, ...},{'userId':'133sf', adminAccess:{checked:true}, ...}, ....]

$scope.notify = function (obj) {
           alert(obj.adminAccess.checked);
}
```

In HTML:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="number.adminAccess.checked" ng-repeat="number in phoneList" ng-change="notify(number)" toggle-class="toggle-positive">
{{numbers.userId}}
</ion-toggle>
```